# Trouble with assertEquals (Java)

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to make a game of "Rock, papers, scissors". I have tests like these:

```
@Test
public void rockBeatsScissors() {
    assertEquals(rock, rock.vs(scissors));
}
```

I think it should be enough to write a function Equals, for example:

```
public class Rock {

Object vs(Scissors s) {
    return new Rock();
}

Object vs(Paper p) {
    return new Paper();
}

Object vs(Rock r) {
    return new Rock();
}

boolean equals(Rock r) {
    return true;
}

boolean equals(Paper p) {
    return false;
}

boolean equals(Scissors s) {
    return false;
}

}
```

(I know I should add a HashCode function, by the way)
I run the tests and I only get failures. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `equals()` method used by `assertEquals()` would be the one which takes `Object` as argument. Right now, you haven't overridden the `Object#equals()` method, but provided your own set of 3 equals method, which wouldn't even be used, and thus the default `Object` class method is used, which just does reference comparison.

You've to give following implementation:

```
/**
 *  Terrible `equals()` method implementation. Just for demonstration purpose.
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Rock;
}
```